# Send txt file from A domain to B domain And run

Tags: php, json, curl, cross-domain

I'm junior php developer with one year experience.

It's my first time to ask for some help

If there's anything that is not appropriate,please tell me,thanks a lot.

Situation:

1.We have two different places(domain A, domain B)

2.When updating the sql on domain A, save a txt file in JSON type as well.(json.txt)

3.Then **"send"** this txt file from domain A to domain B

4.read and decode the txt file on domain B, then used in Updating sql

Question:

that **"send"** in situation 3 is the question need to be helped.

What kind of method can be used in this situation?

Here is the whole process in code :

```
Domain A = "c://example"
Domain B = "220.xxx.xx"
testing file = "sending.txt"
```

DomainA

```
<?php
// this code is on Domain A

include_once "lib/database.php";
$pdo = DB_CONNECT();
$file = "sending.txt";
$f = fopen($file, 'w');

// select data from sql, update and put in array, then save it into txt

$sql = "SELECT id,lastupdated FROM customer";
$pdo -> query($sql);
$rs = $pdo -> query($sql);
foreach ($rs as $key => $row) {
$array[$key]=[
"id" => $row["id"],
"lastupdated" => $row["lastupdated"],
  ];
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer_test (customer_id,lastupdated) VALUES 
(".$row["id"].",'".$row["lastupdated"]."')";
$pdo -> query($sql);
}
$array_json = json_encode($array);
fwrite($f, $array_json);
fclose($f);
?>
```

The Json txt I svaed

```
[{"id":"1","lastupdated":"2017-03-01 13:55:17"},
{"id":"2","lastupdated":"2017-01-08 17:03:39"},
{"id":"3","lastupdated":"2017-02-07 09:34:29"}]
```

Domain B

```
<?php
include_once "lib/database.php";
$pdo = DB_CONNECT();

// get from local txt which has been sent to here From other Domain;

$json_data = file_get_contents('sending.txt');
$array = json_decode($json_data, true);

//then save into same database,but this one is on Domain B.

foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
$id = $array[$i]["id"];
$lastupdated = $array[$i]["lastupdated"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer_test (customer_id,lastupdated) VALUES 
(".$id.",'".$lastupdated."')";
$pdo -> query($sql);
}
?>
```

What code should I add in these two php files?

My boss only give this link to me :
[How to simulate browser form POST method using PHP/cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352830/how-to-simulate-browser-form-post-method-using-php-curl)

But I still don't have any idea at all.

Can't even know where to add my code to test.

Please take a look when you are available with this question.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of Domain A. This generates a post request by the php curl library. You'll need to have it installed and it likely is. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
$ch = curl_init('http://220.xxx.xx');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_json);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($array_json))                                                                       
);
```

And check the data from Domain A by putting this on domain B:

```
var_dump($_RESPONSE);exit;
```

Also, open up the network tab on your element-inspector to get a better idea of what's going on.

```
// get from local txt which has been sent to here From other Domain;
```

It could go the other way around. Domain A doesn't send the text... Domain B retrieves the text from Domain A.

Example from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "c://example/sending.txt"); // Domain A

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      

        // or you could use file_get_contents
        $text = file_get_contents('c://example/sending.txt');
        $text_array = json_decode($text); print_r($text_array);
?>
```